# How would I tag this css with descendant selectors, as recommended in a speed test?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I recently ran a speed test on [GMetrix](http://gmetrix.com) for my asp.net site and it keeps complaining that I should **Tag key with 3 descendant selectors and Class overly qualified with tag**.

For instance, I have this in my stylesheet:

```
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #465c71;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
border-radius: 3px; 
z-index:20;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
z-index:20;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
z-index:20;
}
```

Or, for instance, the speed tests also recommends **3 descendant selectors** for this:

```
/* Top level menu links style */
.sidebarmenu ul li a{
display: block;
overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
color: #dde4ec;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4e667d;
border-right: 1px solid #4e667d;
border: 0px solid #800000;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:link, .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited, .sidebarmenu ul li a:active{
background-color: #465c71; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
border: 0px solid #800000;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited{
border: 0px solid #800000;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:hover{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
border: 0px solid #800000;
}
```

I'm not knowledgeable on CSS at all.  Could somebody please explain how I could use **descendant selectors** here, which I assume means combining these things?  Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: You are using the descendent selector, you probably mean the child selector.

Comment: Thanks Musa; not being good w/ CSS, I was just going off what this online speed test said.  But I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is saying that this declaration is over qualified like

```
.sidebarmenu ul li a
```

So you can also use it simply giving a class to your `<a>` element for example say `.menu_link`

Now you can simply use this in your stylesheet

```
a.menu_link {
   display: block;
   overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
   color: #dde4ec;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 6px;
   border: 1px #4e667d solid;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #4e667d;
   border-right: 1px solid #4e667d;
   border: 0px solid #800000;
}

a.menu_link:link, a.menu_link:visited, a.menu_link:active{
   background-color: #465c71; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
   border: 0px solid #800000;
}

a.menu_link:visited{
   border: 0px solid #800000;
}

a.menu_link:hover{
   background-color: #bfcbd6;
   color: #465c71;
   border: 0px solid #800000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Mr. Alien!  I tried your solution, and maybe it's just this online speed test that's wrong, not me ... I really do appreciate you taking the time to offer your suggestion, and helping me learn a little more about stylesheets!

Comment: Yep ... I think I need to look more into child selectors, rather than descendant selectors, which I'm researching right now .... Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonWeber you welcome, get some good basics, sitepoint reference is really handy..incase you need it http://reference.sitepoint.com/css